# update gallery field in repeater field advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i need to implement a picture in a gallery field inside of a repeater field.

based on the [update_sub_field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_sub_field/) function from acf i use:

```
update_sub_field( array('flat_repeater', $repeaterRow, 'gallery'), $attachmentId, $postId);
```

i cant loop through the repeater field so my selector for the update_sub_field function of acf is

> array('flat_repeater', $repeaterRow, 'gallery')

where

> 'flat_repeater' = the name of the repeaterfield
>
> $repeaterRow = the right row for the repeater where the gallery should
>   be updated
>
> 'gallery' = the name of the gallery field

and

> $attachmentId = the id of the image in the media library from
>   wordpress
>
> $postId = the post id where the repeater/gallery field is.

what am i doing wrong, cause it simply doesn't work.

greetings timotheus

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the field key as the 'name' of the repeater field

`update_field('field_41hdk123', $arrayWithStuff, $postId);`

i hope that solves your problems bro

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it.

perhaps someone needs it sometimes..

the problem was the variable

> $repeaterRow = the right row for the repeater where the gallery should be updated

i always used the key from the repeater array and that one starts with 0.

but repeater rows start with 1 ...

-,-

at leased its solved...

greetings timotheus